# Kafka transaction support in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I will have to create a Kafka producer application that exports a fairly high amount of data from a database with minimal transformation. Each export job would be triggered by a message from another Kafka topic. I was thinking of using the [transactional API](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) provided by Kafka to achieve exactly-once semantics, even if the application fails, and an export job has to be restarted. And doing the export itself with Spark in batch mode. However, I cannot find any clue in the docs if I can have that kind of control over [Spark - Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka) interaction.
Can I specify the commit id? Can I have control over when to initialize, finish the commit?

(I want to use Spark's batch processing capabilites.)

Comment: Any updates concern this problem ? plz